# Memory usage for smallest eigenvalues

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, memory, eigenvalues, sparse-arrays

I have a bunch of hermitian matrices which are huge (of order 2^17 x 2^17) but extremely sparse so that, when I build the matrices, the usage of RAM is low (say of order 1 GB or similar). 
The spectrum of these matrices is symmetrically placed around the origin and I need to collect the most relevant eigenvalues (say 100 of them), both close to the ground state (so the 100 most negative) and close to the center of the spectrum (so, close to the E = 0).

About the most negative eigenvalues I have no problem: I simply shift back the matrix by a large value (so that all the eigenvalues are negative) and then I ask the most relevant: in this way

```
Sort @ Eigenvalues[N @ matrix  , 100 , Method->{"Arnoldi" , "MaxIterations" -> 10^6}]
```

this operation works well and it does not consume a lot of RAM.

The problem arises when I look to the eigenvalues close to E = 0. in this case, my approach would be to do not shift the matrix, and then ask the following command

```
Sort @ Eigenvalues[N @ matrix  , 100 , Method->{"Arnoldi" , "MaxIterations" -> 10^6 , "Criteria" -> "Magnitude", "Shift" -> 0}]
```

However, in this case, the ram consumption becomes enourmous! and it spoils all the advantages of having sparse matrices.

Do you know how I can fix the problem? Am I doing some trivial mistakes?

Also, is this a problem related to mathematica which I could solve by changing the software?

Thank you!

Update: I attach here a piece of code. the matrix of interest is what I call `hamiltonianSparse`. The details to create it do not matter at this stage. I then ask for the excited eigenvalues and one can check that the memory requirement is huge (while asking for the standard Arnoldi procedure to get the eigenvalues with largest magnitude does not require such a huge amount of memory)

```
xCouplingMoving[nGamma_ , kK_ , qQ_ , listIndices_] :=  Block[
{indicesRemoved , elementsRemoved , candidateList , indicesChosen = listIndices[[1]] , indicesToChoose = listIndices[[2]]}, 

indicesRemoved = If[Length @ indicesToChoose >= qQ , RandomSample[Range @ Length @ indicesToChoose , qQ] , Return @ listIndices];
elementsRemoved = indicesToChoose[[indicesRemoved]] // Sort;
candidateList = {PadRight[indicesChosen , Length @ indicesChosen + 1 , {elementsRemoved}] , Delete[indicesToChoose , Partition[indicesRemoved , 1]]};

If[(DeleteDuplicates @ elementsRemoved == elementsRemoved) && (DeleteDuplicates @ candidateList == candidateList) , candidateList , listIndices]

]

xCouplingRegular[nGamma_ , kK_ , qQ_ , listIndices_] := Block[{xCouplingCandidate} , 
xCouplingCandidate = Nest[xCouplingMoving[nGamma , kK , qQ , #] & , listIndices , Round[3 * kK * nGamma]];
If[xCouplingCandidate[[2]] == {} , xCouplingCandidate[[1]] , xCouplingRegular[nGamma , kK , qQ , listIndices]]
]

parityFunc[i_] := (1 + ((-1)^i) )/2;
Ngamma = 40;
nEigen = 15000;
numberOfSamples = Round[nEigen/(2 * Ngamma)];
kK = 1.;
qQ = 4;
listIndices = {{} , (Range @ Ngamma &) /@ Range[kK * qQ] // Flatten};
length=2^(Ngamma/2);
s1 = Symbol["s1"];
s2 = Symbol["s2"];
s3 = Symbol["s3"];
id = Symbol["id"];
s1Mat=SparseArray[{{0 , 1} , {1 , 0}}];
s2Mat=SparseArray[{{0 , -1 * I},{1 * I , 0}}];
s3Mat=SparseArray[{{1 , 0} , {0 , -1}}];
idMat=SparseArray[{{1 , 0} , {0 , 1}}];
(*leviCivitaSymbol = Signature /@ Permutations @ {s1 , s2 , s3} * (Permutations @ {s1 , s2 , s3} );*)

gammaList[d_] :=  PadRight[PadLeft[If[OddQ @ d , {s1} , {s2}] , IntegerPart[(d - 0.1)/2] + 1 , s3] , Ngamma/2 , id];
toMat[list_] := KroneckerProduct @@ (list /. {s1 -> s1Mat , s2 -> s2Mat , s3 -> s3Mat , id -> idMat}); 
nullMatrix = SparseArray[{1 , 1} -> 0 , {length , length}];

eigenCollection = 
Function[{x} ,
(
SeedRandom[x];

xCoupling = xCouplingRegular[Ngamma , kK , qQ , listIndices];


hamiltonianSparse = SparseArray[Fold[#1 +  1/4 * RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.,Sqrt[6./((kK / Binomial[Ngamma , 4] ) Ngamma^4.)]]] * Dot @@ (Function[{y} , toMat @ gammaList[y] ] /@ #2) & , nullMatrix , xCoupling]  , {length , length} , 0 ];


Sort @ Eigenvalues[N @ hamiltonianSparse , 2 * Ngamma , Method -> {"Arnoldi" , "MaxIterations" -> 10^6 , "Criteria" -> "Magnitude", "Shift" -> 0}]


)
] /@ Range @ numberOfSamples;
```

I attach for completeness a matrix plot of a slightly smaller matrix obtained with the same algorithm

[image: matrixplot]

Comment: Is it viable to square your matrix? For sparse matrices squaring the matrix should not be all that time- or RAM-consuming. Then look at the smallest eigenvalues...

Comment: Hi @MariusLadegårdMeyer . Your suggestion is smart, but probably not applicable in this particular case. When I said that the eigenvalues are symmetric around the origin, I cheated a bit. They are approximately symmetrically distributed, but not exactly. So, if I am understanding your suggestion, by squaring the matrix I would remain with the eigenvalues close to 0 as the dominant ones, but I could not figure out whether, before the squaring, these eigenvalues were positive or negative. you agree?

Comment: Do you have the RAM to also store the eigenvectors and not only the eigenvalues? If yes, then you can use  `Eigensystem`, find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A^2$, and then dot the first row of $A$ (**not** $A^2$!) by an eigenvector. If the result has the same sign as the first element of the eigenvector, the eigenvalue is positive, and if the sign changes, the eigenvalue is negative.

Comment: Unfortunately not: since I need large statistics (these matrices are random) I need to run these process in parallel and so I do not have enough memory to store also the eigenvectors. Thank you very much, in any case! your suggestions are inspiring! let us see if there is a way to use some mathematica built-in methods!

Comment: Are the matrices hermitian?

Comment: yes, they are. They represent hamiltonians for physical systems.

Comment: Have you tried the FEAST method for Eigenvalues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107293/discussion-between-dario-rosa-and-marius-ladegard-meyer).

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer OP pointed out that the eigenvalues cluster around 0. All eigenvalue algorithms have problems with degenerate eigenvalues, and since eigenvalues of the squared matrix would cluster even more around 0, squaring the matrix would make things even worse.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, good point, I did not think of that!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: but so do you think that the poor performance in terms of memory is related to the fact the eigenvalues around 0 are almost degenerate?

Comment: Yes I am. Degeneracy makes the problem hard.

Comment: But the memory consumption is probably caused `"MaxIterations" -> 10^6`. I think it automatically increase the size of the used Krylov subspace. If the Krylov subspace is too large then one does not benefit fromt he fact that the matrix is sparse. You can try to manually set the size of the Krylov space, e.g. with `Method -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10^6, "BasisSize" -> 1000 , 
  "Criteria" -> "Magnitude", "Shift" -> 0}`.

Comment: Thank you! I try!

Comment: It does not work. The memory consumption is still huge.

Comment: Hm. It is hard to help here without an example matrix...

Comment: Hi @HenrikSchumacher. I attach in the main message a piece of code. You do not have to worry about the details: the matrix that I want to study is called hamiltonianSparse. You will see (at least, in my tests this is what I am observing) that when with Arnoldi I ask for the eigenvalues with the largest magnitude the memory usage is quite small. However, when I use the shift and invert technique to go to the excited states the memory requirement is huge

Comment: My only slightly unreasonable request: could you post the result of `MatrixPlot[N @ hamiltonianSparse]` in your question?